# POST Request with basic auth in Swift + get params + post params (using Alamofire or RxSwift or any thing else)

Tags: swift

I try to send POST request
on server http://test.alex009.ru/ set HTTP authentication (alice / Qwerty1234)

execute the query:

POST http://test.alex009.ru/alice.php with parameter transfer:

get parameter is "secret" = alex009
post parameter "input" = (entered text from the text field)

in the header must specify the type of the received content 
- application / json

My code is:

I have this for HTTP basic auth

```
let username = "alice"
let password = "Qwerty1234"
let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
let authenticationToken = base64LoginString
```

and I need to post thith get parameters:

```
let parameters : [String: AnyObject] = ["secret" : "alex009"]
```

then I create NSMutableURLRequest:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://test.alex009.ru/alice.php")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON
        (request, _) = encoding.encode(request, parameters: parameters)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let values = ["input" : "textFromTextFild"]
        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])
        print(request)
```

and send it with Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(request)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                // do whatever you want here
                switch response.result {
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                case .Success(let responseObject):
                    print(responseObject)
                }
        }
```

and get response from server :

{ URL: my url  }
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 406" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 406}

where is my mistake?

Comment: Why are you setting the `HTTPBody` of the request, when you already called `encoding.encode`?

Comment: Are you sure the server was expecting a JSON request, and not that it expected a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request and merely that it was going to provide a JSON response?

Comment: I am sure that it is application / json

Comment: :) it should have been Accept  instead of Content-Type, because it is received content  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers

Answer (score 0):

```html
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

let params: Parameters = [ "paramsString": param]


Alamofire.request( baseUrlDev, method: .post, parameters:params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {(response: DataResponse<Any>) in
            
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if let data = response.result.value{
                    HyberLogger.debug(response.result.value)
                    
                }
                break
                
            case .failure(_):HyberLogger.debug("Unknown Error")
                    }
                }
                
                break
            }
        }
```